# Load a page at a specific (location) div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, offset

I have a question relating to loading a page (initial load, not anchors) to a certain div that is not at the top of the page.

For example, I have **div#one** at the top of the page, and it is full width, and full height of my screen. Underneath that, I have another div, **div#two**, that is the same size, but hidden beneath the first one.

Now, I want the page to load div#two right off the bat, and I can scroll back up if I want. What I have works, but it scrolls down in a second after load:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#two').offset().top
        }, 'fast');
    });
```

**What I need is to eliminate the animate in this equation.** Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop($('#two').offset().top)`

Comment: You can also add the anchor directly to the url: `mypage.html#two`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `document.location.href="#two";`. :-)

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer if it's what you're looking for please.